# Activate tracing using WLST for OSB

Tags: weblogic, osb, wlst

I can manually enable tracing for a proxy service on Oracle Service Bus Console. I would like to do that same action using WLST. I've been able to write scripts that enable or disable the service, but not the tracing feature so far?

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it via standard OSB customisation. I work around this by altering the sbconfig.jar before upload.

https://github.com/tomecode/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator